# Using GPUImageLookupFilter on a movie file produces black screen

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am moving my code over from a still image application to one that produces movie files. There is a problem however with the following code where the final output is a black movie screen using the GPUImageLookupFilter filter. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong or what I may have missed.

```
Header File Sample
GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource;
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter;
GPUImageMovie *movieFile;
GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
@property(nonatomic,strong) GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource;



Main File
filter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];

            self.lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ExtremeVintage1.png"]];

            GPUImageLookupFilter * filterLookup = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];

            [self.lookupImageSource addTarget:filterLookup];

            [self.lookupImageSource processImage];

            [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter addFilter:filterLookup];



            [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filterLookup]];
            [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setTerminalFilter:filterLookup];


            [movieFile addTarget:filter];
```

Thanks

**** UPDATE *****

New code

```
self.lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"ExtremeVintage1.png"]];
            [self.lookupImageSource processImage];

            filter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
            [lookupImageSource addTarget:filter];

            [movieFile addTarget:filter];
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this an ARC-enabled project? If so, you're not holding on to a strong reference to your lookupImageSource GPUImagePicture instance past the method where you've set up the above. As soon as you exit that method, the GPUImagePicture providing your lookup will be deallocated and you'll lose your lookup texture as a result.

Try making lookupImageSource a strongly held instance variable of your class, so that it persists beyond the setup code above.

Comment: Hi Brad, it is a ARC enabled project and I have tried moving the code outside of the method (see updated code above) but unfortunately still no luck. If I change the filter to a simple vignette it runs without a problem. The player will run each frame without an issue but the output to the screen is black.

Comment: @ORStudios - In the above, there's no need to wrap the lookup filter in a filter group. Have you tried using the lookup filter directly with the movie file, instead of going through the group?

Comment: Hi, I have taken it out of the filter group and placed it on its own. It is showing but it looks very strange, I am using the supplied lookup png (512 x 512) and it seems to display the picture in a block format.

Comment: @ORStudios - I think I see part of what's wrong here. You're adding the movie to be processed as an input to your filter after you've added the lookup image. The lookup filter expects the actual lookup image to be the second input into that filter, not the first. You can either reverse the order in which these inputs are added to the filter or use `-addTarget:atTextureLocation:` for the lookup image source, with a texture location of 1. Look at how the Amatorka and other filters based on the lookup do this, as examples.

Comment: Brilliant! thanks for the help Brad. I ended up adding the -addTarget:atTextureLocation: to the code so it solved the issue. Thanks again and great framework.